# Accessing The Symfony Server From An IPhone

Tags: symfony, networking, server

I have a Symfony in built server running on my machine, the address is as follows

> http://127.0.0.1:8000

I would like to test the API via my IPhone but I am a little unsure how to go about doing this. I have looked at other posts posts and they say point to the host machine but the above server address is different to the host machine.

Comment: That is a loopback address, and it can never be used outside a host. Everything sent to that address simply loops back inside the host. See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/44635/8499) and answer.

Comment: If you're on local network, you can maybe access it with the local IP...

Comment: Ok thanks guys, so I am guessing that I need to point to the Mac IP address then? It will automatically find it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project root, run the php built in web server like this:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public/
```

Or the symfony one if you have it:

```
bin/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then, check your LAN ip. If you are on Linux you can do `ifconfig` a look for the wlan adapter.

Then, go to that ip:port in your phone's browser, connected in the same Local Network.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, been trying to sort this for a while. I was getting 403 errors but this has solved it.